# React Native - Android - Red screen error showing on publicly released production app

Tags: android, react-native

According to RN docs this should be impossible but I'm getting a red screen error on my app downloaded from the playstore. The playstore version generally works fine but there was a null value on one of the screens and it popped a redscreen.

Definitely uploaded the release version of APK using `Build --> Generate Signed Bundle/APK`. I'm totally at a loss of where else to look as I can't find any mentions of similar situations through searches.

`Build.gradle` file looks like:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        debug {
    debuggable false
}
```

**Edit for additional steps I've tried:**

Tried following this RN guide for releasing as well: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android to no avail.

Confirmed the apk I'm using is in-fact a release build using `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`

Testing using a console.error() just after I see the app load successfully and that consistently shows a red screen.

Comment: I am facing with the same issue. Is this happening in IOS Build?